# How to take the value of a variable to the paragraph tag?

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid, paragraph

I am having a problem to send the code to my `<p>` tag where am I going wrong?

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p id="100"> </p>
  <script>
    var dictionary
    var lower

    function start() {
      var dictionary = "house";
      lower = dictionary.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
    document.getElementById("100").innerHTML == document.getElementById([lower]).value
    start()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly you wanna do with `document.getElementById([lower]).value`? Which value you want to set to `p` tag?

Comment: @decpk i want to send the value of `var dictionary` after sending it to `var lower` and making it small

Comment: where are you sending? and what exactly do you mean by `making it small`. It is so unclear what exactly do you want?

Comment: @decpk "by making it small" i mean converting the whole string to lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remarks are in the comment in code snippet.

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="A100"> </p>
<script>
var dictionary,lower;
function start(){dictionary="house";
lower=dictionary.toString().toLowerCase();
//you need to return something for the function output to be consumed somewhere else 
return lower;
}
//you use start output to render innerhtml
// you dont do another document.get because lower is not a dom element its is Js object and we have used start return to make is consumable
// == is comparative = is used as setter we are setting not comparing as code would suggest 
document.getElementById("A100").innerHTML=start();
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Local scope example as suggested by Mathi;

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="A100"> </p>
<script>

function start(){
let dictionary, lower;
dictionary="house";
lower=dictionary.toString().toLowerCase();
 
return lower;
}
document.getElementById("A100").innerHTML=start();
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: There are two strange things. You declare dictionary twice and use lower from the global space, which does not really make sense ;-)

Comment: @Matthi since it was clear as of rest of OP scope so I didn't mess about much with scoping as such. Using var from global or let from local they both stand valid depending upon OPs own context of how things play with each other However, taking you suggestion I would include another example using local scope only :)

Comment: @Syed I did not the suggest the code above! Still does not make any sense. It would be nice to leave good code here for others who have similar issues.
I already committed an answer with a nicer solution, but it seems you have not accepted it. For this, I am out.

Comment: @Matthi you suggestion is valid and was rightly so that is declaring dictionary twice which was an oversight on my part as I didn't fully remove all possible typos for OPs code.  and please be noted your suggestion is related to scope i.e. global vs local - not per say the code beautification. nevertheless your above suggestions are meaningful and have been accepted in that sense. thank fo your contributions

Answer (score 3):

What your script does is:

1. Try to get element with id "100" (btw. starting ids with a number is bad practice although it might work in some browsers — see [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html#answer-79022)). It might fail to detect the element, because of bad naming.
2. Expecting the element would have been found, you don’t assign the new `innerHTML` (which would work with a `=`), but make a comparison with a `==`.
3. Then you try to find an element by `[lower]`. First, `getElementById` expects a string and second `lower` is `undefined` at this moment. It hasn’t been set yet. It will be set in the next line, where you execute `start()`. Also notice that only `<p>` does not have a `value`. In this case better go with `innerText`. If you just want the paragraph to show the value of `lower`, just assign lower like: `document.getElementById("100").innerText = lower;`
4. `toString()` is not needed if the argument is always a string. Then it would just be

```js
var dictionary = "HouSe";
document.getElementById("a100").innerText = dictionary.toLowerCase();
```

A working example could be:

```js
function toLowerCaseString(value) {
    return value.toString().toLowerCase();
}

var dictionary = "HouSe";

document.getElementById("a100").innerText=toLowerCaseString(dictionary);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="a100"></p>
  </body> 
</html>
```